# Emission plane is casting a shadows in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

My emission objects (which are flat planes) are casting shadows parallel to their faces. Rotating the planes causes the shadow line to move but not to diffuse.

Blender screenshot:

[image]

Render with shadows:

[image]

Under Cycles Settings I have tried turing off shadows for both the emission objects and the ground, but the shadow is still there. What do I have to do to fix the issue?

Comment: It's strange that it doesn't work for you. Have you selected just one emission object and then disabled the *Shadow* setting (unchecked *Shadow* checkbox in the *Cycles Settings* panel)? BTW I've changed your tag- it should be *Cycles* instead of *Blender-Render*.

Comment: I tried just the one that was casting a shadow but it remained. Matt's answer was what I thought the issue was but I wanted to make sure. Thanks for changing the tag.

Comment: I would comment, but I don't have the reputation to comment yet, (but i can still answer? weird) but wouldn't it be easier to clip the emission plane into the floor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not casting shadows, they only emit light from the faces, not form the edges. You can try to extrude the faces, but even so, the faces on the edges won't emit enough light to match the one coming from the front and back faces.

[image: edges emission]

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure because in the past I don't recall having this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to make 2 materials with emission shaders, one of them will be the current material you made, and the other will have a much higher power.
After doing that, assign the 1st material to the faces, and the 2nd material to the edge faces. With trial and error you can balance the power of the 2nd material to make the faces in the edges emit the same light as the faces.